# pyodbc update query to SQL server gets ingored

Tags: python, sql, sql-update, pyodbc

I have some python code where I am trying to update records in a SQL server. Here's the python script (written in Spyder):

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("my_connection_string")
crsr = conn.cursor()
crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM [Cards]")
for record in crsr.fetchall():
    print(record)
crsr.execute("UPDATE [Cards] SET [Card URL] = 'a url'")
print("updated") 
crsr.close()
del crsr
conn.close()
```

When I run it, the select query seems to run just fine, as I can see my table data printed in the console. The update query appears to run, but there's no results shown in SQL Server Management Studio. Neither Spyder nor SQL Server throw any errors. I have re-executed the query in SQL Server and the update never appears. Here's a screenshot of what I am seeing (SQL Server on the left, Spyder on the right)

[image]

Is this a python issue? or a SQL issue? Is there a property I should look at to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you need to commit the transaction explicitly or set auto commit on? What happens if you fetch the data again after your `UPDATE` in the application, can you see the changes there? And BTW, your `UPDATE` query as it stand will change all `[Cards]`, you're maybe missing a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Autocommit was the culprit. Thanks for pointing me in that direction. I was able to get the update query to run by adding "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;" before and "COMMIT TRANSACTION;" after the update query.